# Soap Response getting printed by default

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

Soap Response getting printed by default without uses of
 echo,print_r,var_dump.. i am getting output lile this .. would you
 please solve this problem.

**Request:**

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    require_once('nusoap.php');
    $client = new nusoap_client('http://soap.xxxx.xxxx.com:8080/xxxxx.php?wsdl',true);
    echo $error = $client->getError();
    $soap_username='xxxxxxx';
    $soap_password=md5('xxxxxx');
    $header='<user xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$soap_username.'</user><password xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$soap_password.'</password>';
    $client->setHeaders($header);

    $info = new StdClass();
    $info->AccountId = xxxx;
    $info->CDRFileName = "xxxxxxx.csv.zip";
    $param = array($info);
    $result = $client->call('CdrFile.getFile',$param);
?>
```

> **Response (without any sort of print commands):**
>
> array(4) { [0]=> array(9) { ["pos"]=> int(0) ["children"]=> string(2)
>   "|1" ["cdata"]=> string(0) "" ["depth"]=> int(0) ["parent"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(8) "envelope" ["name"]=> string(8)
>   "Envelope" ["attrs"]=> array(4) { ["xmlns:SOAP-ENV"]=> string(41)
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ["xmlns:xsd"]=> string(32)
>   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ["xmlns:xsi"]=> string(41)
>   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ["xmlns:SOAP-ENC"]=>
>   string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" }
>   ["namespace"]=> string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>   } [1]=> array(9) { ["pos"]=> int(1) ["children"]=> string(2) "|2"
>   ["cdata"]=> string(0) "" ["depth"]=> int(1) ["parent"]=> int(0)
>   ["status"]=> string(4) "body" ["name"]=> string(4) "Body" ["attrs"]=>
>   array(0) { } ["namespace"]=> string(41)
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" } [2]=> array(11) {
>   ["pos"]=> int(2) ["children"]=> string(2) "|3" ["cdata"]=> string(0)
>   "" ["depth"]=> int(2) ["parent"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> string(6)
>   "struct" ["status"]=> string(6) "method" ["name"]=> string(23)
>   "CdrFile.getFileResponse" ["attrs"]=> array(1) { ["xmlns:ns1"]=>
>   string(11) "urn:AvaVoip" } ["namespace"]=> string(11) "urn:AvaVoip"
>   ["result"]=> array(1) { ["return"]=> &string(18026647)
>   "PKBC[$˜ñÞ¸Ã1176-20131001.csvUT   ýcKRdKRUx´[]o¹r}Ï¯0ôÜëaU‘ERO¹Aò–î0ø¹W€¯mXZà^
>   ?>‡Ó=ëµším)²eËšÖÌTóL}œS,>¶ÇÇ‡ÏŸ><Ôå±=ýöåÃÓÃßÛRËçOŸZyZ?nÏª¿}MOøaÉ?¦ü±}»rWÒÇ­~ø’¾>ýóÝÝ2>|úu}¼<|ú0.|øØ~¦nŸþù¥ÝÜ^{{üÝ‹Ó§ÿßnäË×ÏOŸËçãÚ×ö÷ÏOíCªõ+~»|m[zl?ÿöµ|·”’~{lKù[úúëí¿o÷¿=þòµõ‡,OéKmOŸ®¿ý’`œZvô
>       ‰·d—;6$¿˜ø‹˜w,÷ÎßÛx·]%ó‹¡wÆÜº·0‡…),J^˜½ D‹óÖáË;^¾\$8ÃþÇ.Ô«iÖjl•¬£(ªlM*¹–XþUÝ{ŠïIè½
>       —ôh’§¹\ˆ˜@ÞórdjØZØ¿ÇBÞ“Ñ÷^—…t1ïrÄ}òöÂq–»¿üöøô5}|Hï~y÷?ÿùïøþo_súÔî¾%DãwËw÷bî®|)…
>   B¤ª{@‚+
>   ZLŽ!uXâÀ±™ÚIk¯ž-áÙ\ö.ðe920ƒÁùÛ¢·ûšbð—Ú>¦‡ú|õX¼Ý­Sïyâþžá.,Ž~¼þHA¯ë÷IL2Lœ©øåØmŒ‘ŒID%=_?)\H½^¼zÀHì_Äê<œ}žÜó5þÒ   BpèÝÜ«ŠWª3&Z»Càú°z‚ãªÉzuD‘²ß³ñ9YS]j½=GÂ‹­¹xAÐªqÀüÈÔ1Ì´øp}Ý‰ÿj3’Íó°7¹[4ß³ÞM®:‡<—+ÎZQÙ#AðŠÕ'z@J(°Ö9Š°
>   öc‹Ý'DE
>   OÏ&[—/BÁ9 ÈHG–Ž0ä×œÂð×Ï¿=ýíÝ¤Ç§wÏ€Pþý’éžì½uwÏ¯²½g7¢ÃŒ;ºBîEm;¯°¿Ø¦
>   VT+Ã:Þ1â»x¦¨¶F'»ø@èÄjåBYÇ§tdé
>       Rq›ür¯„W=[¶‹×¤ðÝU¾Ç_F¢DB^P~¿Eöf!\ù †é]o‘;pÏ=Ø‚PlvA{aŸƒï1µô~!ÄHÕ-G¦Ž=k[È™£áŒFy¾nçîYvh8½F|ùUÊ¹ˆ¨ª;,àêfKœZkMÍv§>Ù¤9Ö¬FmONŒµ;,2ŠKråöðI-G–~$‘Hø    ÿýùë#Ïp
>   1Ïr…Ü“ìÓæõê`óc—Jî
>   £¢›˜ÛæMcñ¿íI>aaÏa’SµÁ]Èqô*¬ñe.Áß•ÒzE#Ï×ÌáÞÚ¯øÀš]i
>       Š"x‡ÜdE¢ç»S$ßº-™º+…JiØeMü„rÃ¤ Ã‹–#Sž6ÇË^L¬t‡ýÓk–>jœnˆ‰k¶h™‡ê8•Zno{Ì—m.aŸ-àGŒ¢qAº7D–åÈÒ¨Eüý_ê|‰pïAâ"WØ%FÜxœ:ÆZN5ÅL
>   Ñ{£v¶ÕËæ%)íq|Î‰Ž½kª˜™:ã1ò'ŽAv‡›9†c€ÆŒ*â­±Î¡îÏð°võ
>       ª# —PÊˆkz€ È6jÙ¥gS”Sr°W¿˜Z:Ç‹gôçP€S ]è-[Ç2wŠMˆ™Ä-jê$ìY[’JK0˜ÈåêvÁ¡Èj…/°‹÷GµË‘©SÙb‚Ãq’Ðó¾à
>       ²ÉdxÌ4iòÊ(`!ãí
>       ÈUÅ$#84ëñÍÁsŸÃ0¤‰ºˆÁ†ƒ±â–#KSÂ÷:Œ_ >FL¸—â@²Ú± Œ{õq ŠU‡¹‘
>       £¬\¤„ E$C|+¸b$ïx&•’í×$}--G¦~àPa×ÞÁË¡ÓP½ª¢5jU ©¬umb…3ÄL.UJjÁüZKêÝí|Â§J½Ó¤„,œ_Ž,@â¥ ÂŸÇWåwÏSã†•Yh¬i’“TBwQšØœ
>   1É÷ÞErÀ±óS3UßA0!Ú4„°Y:Ó¢x©?èKq`»ò_Fdš†Æ*Ì¥t¦DÆ¶Ì¸1Igp¤¤¢­öÅ”Ö•K¹@ºf—#KoÎ´£q§
>       †EŠ¸eJõ£Ù4uZ£‚|©½yï¥”ñd× Ç’Š‰>€Åíè%“
>       ðÂ
>       q[Î;ÑåÈÔ•ïýá{ýË~ù'Yƒ9ùéìFS¬cßžA°æH²‚€³ƒGøz€KàGä¶#Ðß­D¶
>   £fz0ÐåÈÔù9^ø*Ž_áÞFg±òiÑMƒ6S}†š¤Ô=ð `JM¥2#Uî"£1²Ë
>   O~cRKî/ž 2)þ“Òxå:”¶MJË•sˆ>™Ñ)Á¹5’°+bZˆº
>       ±ÄÄ!.G¦~žî"ÿ 8ðIãæ¬ÓnƒIÄZ œjôì¹‚[CC»Râ¾/á4W
>        J~$ç·²1±ôçh¼¬Ÿ;¼Âœ‡Áß ±âÀÞxÖ‡5_j…hô>Ùfp½¶Ñ¯+¤È ‰ö‰ZBC‘€·xJ´Ë‘¡30¼´zÆ“0
>   zÂ†Ë]Í8KL:ánÍ™\ð“!Ó{¥$ø?bý„2weCñ–¹4ñàN‘øÖßŸX:C°ÏU
>   §—?ÚtÖl¥YäÈÐ”<¸µ+}µ6ñ®ø >KæJi]áîBä‹ ®³‹ 7@]Å
>   nM™‰¥øAðßîð5Ùíù°0dMÈÈ€(ÀvêºF…WIx’rê‚T7TxoÅ¶²kg»h:[#€#@n›7Ù91õçþp}Ù«ðàÓr^¼¥‰
>   |sZ¥[3¢øRjqxâµwËÄÑ=©fæÝ®‹r¯-_o<ºf9²t&Oœ‹–óî@w‹[Ávþ
>       â7]ýÚ…°)·Ò ™"'+1#9fÜUõªÕÇ¼kM‰ ‚Èe920]ôÿ‡6Lu…ŸfFÕ·BÉðÛé'ï7}Åd'c
>       ·s÷‰'†Ètœ5ïZT5¡´Ö
>       AQXJo–#S?¡R bl÷…›°    8"„-*´‚aïÁ¥“rÕÞùaO šŒ¾åÍ    öÞÚ Äž\ûêÿ[:´HsÎÍ¹cÜv/Pä
>   ¯¾£J¹VÈnçKrÝí÷|dÄ?!"ZB€‰åÈÒÛhó»Šp
>   Ás§°R¬†X*Ü?*>õ„O˜ZVó~&$š{1r*\e92u¦&°MI~ibØF/,¼zÍ±0Újx]k»Æ‹µâðÌx¤¸5f§†Þz4dÀ
>   ¯Áã~,eZâÚš%í’  &¡´SAFp
>   Žá;æÈ ÉdäGæÑ°«[ÌLØÙ{iŠ0çqûzöÖvœ·ê·ÕÑA’êƒFi
>   •É«KÖ”²ïQ·¢1º
>       ÞÛD¼\Ž,êÌžäñUõÁ’ÒØ˜Ÿ®_¶~lìƒ*jO9¡8ÀdD†75‡Ên?c¼ÉÙ®õafàÍIB8Ÿ‡Š4Ë:‹À{öª‚Ùjc(Ö$,$kVMÛmí#‡eî>û–ãQ#7ŽÉ­#Kgz
>       áU©‘ÝkÊ¥Cö2ø>­koÁøj+‘ÝœT Ã¤›Ü¼$ûý&…kZsc {oí   Ö4Õ&Kß<Ázv£«6Y;Ñê ¶†‚¼æ rŒÍz›Ç] b¡±Ù)'.=hHùP9ØÇ5
>       L-½ù®¥¸“(@.¹1´¹›Š€ÚÎ  ÓÊm¯)ÅæŒM)d?ZFxGÐŸ18YªNôc{ÿ£(x
>       Ù½Éé‰¥3ñðªV›åÓhŒ‰j£Â–ÕM}bžäž`PÎÙHWä¢*NÒ>r;æìsëŽLÜ2ãÄÀ›3gzíc6O'·õ½À‚ü¬ÑHfÕOâ
>   ¤±R  “iL
>       çv¶»²À­—TÅ_ð¨'ãnûS{K?cÃÒÒù˜;ºÄÕ>lÖ)´áþM£â“‹fÎ¶J/Ô«Ù‰Âòmi’CqHpî¶‰½7õ3p ”’mÒ*"'N]b‹°Å˜\öÌ­6©Æ¶Ñ$.”¾ß©ÓìCCò€#ï‡YŽ,ª–/™i=»øl-Å9
>   g°&C#'²Yká^ìÔ°±»aç)ÛWB\x³Æ‰©ŸÓýo=î`±†s$Þ:
>       ZÝ¨Ž¾¶äAŒ µåŠœQÈì÷§À ±zö³.WI}dê'tám8  ÈC¼’YKºwCùÎ€Ø6êX}ÉøC¡Ž¡T6™sì
>   sˆu×…6´×.äÆô›•ÛNÝÄÔ›³OûÃØÃÙ`· y0ñ©´&Ùf$…›C^díãTG2U¹Øœ5Ry*ûž[ÉÑ´rAp#%@’/G–~Ôw·nüëZ
>   Öäº;#‹ÿ6p0¥S´Íx™’ú8d$!»VP
>   }¤dÇ$ý~Ô!Q(¡†FäÔ8RÞ‘¥·u±z>Oè•U®VuL¬MaØöza%Ô4z r¿g¨-‚Ð>è;NœA¾‘ÜÎØm˜–OëníèT@¡\ÊxnÌ6ˆƒ²°†;¾û²¬çUÇ
>   ‹5Ù1,G¦ÞÜ†a·s›ö…< »¶ßTàý  Ò“Ce¤ÈZ¶~xÈ¾+KÍ"…‡ÚIuT-G¦NM
>   ¿*Uª9h2L®º?tê…â|ŽümPTBspŠ”´Û–Ä”æÆNŒ­ûézd…T›&*Rc`ñÈÔ›·ê•Æ8æ]½õdÇ+ñ…56ÆLè˜k44¬¯Úª­ÕvÓb
>   Ôýi=­`á·ýº‰·œÊ'—ïíè=ÅqØde6>óÄà·‰Ž`çÑJ9\»Nj©"7„EŒû½ëÜ™K
>       H æFÌz@ojê 8,–_„˜³ê°Ï«òÁø<ÚŠeÍ­‚Ad´‰¬¸”,BÜ´Ð½ßO #_Tð¥Kô^±t¿5¢&–Þ<=ª= Â8•5Úb·$3;w4PX™¤áØjç"ÝVN_ãôQ
>       t=ÃšÍ¾XZÛrð—q*˜o;Væô9´?Œ|½.7ºÓ`®ÓãëÈ4þ…ù2ýêÜ¬EÂ3)ø” ÁQ÷|0ÅCNác{¡z®5_HF§}—#SoO$UÏ«|ÓY`Üï4El[ÙL•¬-U´iO( Q
>       ò%Ù;9»‹ ‰(+(®W>ñ–¼YzóØðÓR9=yeÌ·È@jhÚ¥°ÛAæ2æÞGeð¨ÙiˆÙ÷±;«¡¸ÝÆÝ˜‡,
>       ”•1d¯Ûÿ‰¥7îÂŒIÖƒý©I‚Wéo¼âÍ,MÊÖ…‘&í%Š
>       žI¢ùVO£ sî¤•¢¨Ôšè2Zü:z2Ë‘¥EmñªQá1ê|qÏÒ"´¢nìõLéŽ²JÐáê Rªé Ó6¢‚ Dì´f‹ÁA\€xÞü¶—µ7u¦|¾¬=Ãi dè‹p›ûae;m×ò–+Áš@…
>   ‘ª¦âÇ•ÈEF •=±Ö”ÄšP+T¼l'm&¦Þ|îg9 }‡ À6NýaÍ•”S‰ˆ
>   JIÂÏéÑ÷‚:r]æ~xœµ¡â^àìG¤åÈÔ›3êO£`í÷pÀû½óSwØâUŠIC‡nM+ÙŒí=#ÛZl=é¾[+aŒyÜöpöÞ–RÝ×†p
>   þ÷8è@£Ó¹¹€‹Æ‡b|+ ºÂ¸Âô!)jè¾\&TEÇ Q…ìè¬™ú¡Î!æº‘&kÏ~Ž³

Comment: the response is a zip file in base64 binary.. thus it looks messy.

Comment: Can we see your code where you make the soap request?

Comment: Please edit your question and add this code there